# Best way to solve an equation in form f(x)=K*u(x)

Tags: matlab

I am solving an equation of motion, which is described e.g. as

```
syms u1 u2 f3 f4;
K=magic(4);
f=[2 3 f3 f4];
u=[u1 u2 9 7];
```

where both f and K include variables.

Which is the easiest or/and most efficient way to do this? I want something like

```
solution=solve(f==K*u);
```

and don't know if it's the efficient way.

Comment: Have a look at [`linsolve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/linsolve.html). You might have to rearrange your system though.

Answer (score 2):

Your equations are not yet in standard form, yet are reducible to it.

Compute

```
>> syms u1 u2 f3 f4;
>> K = magic(4);
>> f = [2 3 f3 f4].';
>> u = [u1 u2 9 7].';

>> K*u - f

ans =
      16*u1  +  2*u2            + 116
       5*u1  + 11*u2            + 143
       9*u1  +  7*u2 - f3       + 138
       4*u1  + 14*u2      - f4  + 142
```

In which I altered the formatting for clarity. From this we can see that if we define

```
b = [-116 -143 -138 -142].';
A  = [16  2   0   0 
       5 11   0   0 
       9  7  -1   0
       4 14   0  -1];
```

Then we have an equation in standard form

```
A*X = b
```

where

```
X = [u1 u2 f3 f4].'
```

Then, it is a simple matter of

```
>> X = A\b
ans =
   -5.963855421686747e+000    % u1
   -1.028915662650603e+001    % u2
   +1.230120481927711e+001    % f3
   -2.590361445783132e+001    % f4
```

Comment: Thank you. My matter is exactly getting the equations in standard form automatically. Saying, creating the matrix A and b..

Comment: @Caniko: Isn't it possible to convert the implementation that computes `K`, `u` and `f` to return the `A` and `b`? Seems far easier than trying to generate if from symbolics...

Comment: It's nearly impossible..Unfortunately. This option is not available for me. That's why I'm asking this question :)